# What's the difference between dynamicDisplay and Display?

Tags: arcobjects

The overriden function is 
public override void DrawDynamicLayer(esriDynamicDrawPhase DynamicDrawPhase, IDisplay Display, IDynamicDisplay dynamicDisplay)

What's the difference between dynamicDisplay and Display?  They both have similar functions like "DrawPolygon" and "DrawText"

and then how about if I cast my map to an ActiveView and access ScreenDisplay, how are all of these display types different?  How should I know which one to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the DynamicDisplay when you want to animation or do real-time tracking in a map. [About dynamic display](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/c9e1ccf5-df7d-44d3-a2da-d916f65fd94a.htm)

See also [About Dynamic Display in 10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003t3000000).